# How to update jQuery on WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

how to update jQuery version 1.6.2 to 1.8.2 on WordPress ?

I have tried using the jQuery updater plugin and the following code :

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your theme or a plugin is already overriding jquery with an old version. The latest version of WordPress should be using 1.11.2. The solution might be to prevent WordPress' version of jquery from being overridden in the first place.

Comment: check if it is being added manually in a script tag within theme template

Comment: thanks i have checked the theme template for script tags but i couldnt find any code that might be related. How can override the override to use 1.8.2 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend preventing WordPress from loading its version of jQuery. The WP is using jQuery 1.11.2 but it also runs in noconflict mode.

The purpose of noConflict mode is to help ensure there are not compatibility problems between jQuery and other javascript libraries loaded into WordPress. In short, noConflict mode means that the standard $ short cut used in jQuery (and other javascript libraries) is not usable, and must be replaced with jQuery.

It looks like you have checked the theme template. I would recommend looking into the header.php, footer.php and functions.php files. These are likely the places you would find either the function that adding jQuery or the embedded jQuery scripts.

If you happen to find the where it is, your best bet is to remove it (if it is anywhere but your functions.php file), and replace it with this:

```
function sof_load_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', '1.8.2', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sof_load_scripts' );
```

If you are confident that your theme will work with the latest WP version of jQuery then use just the following:

```
function sof_load_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sof_load_scripts' );
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is for the frontend, so there's no need of `if ( !is_admin() )`

Comment: You are correct d79, however it wasnt mentioned whether it was front end or not. :)